# Set ticks according to formula

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, axis-labels

Given a figure created by spectrogram function, how do I set the ticks according to the following formula?

```
(12 × log2 (f / 440)) + 69
```

[`f` is the current value on the axis, and the formula's result should replace it]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question right...There might be a more efficient way, but I think this works:

```
data = rand(1,1000);

plot(data)
f = get(gca,'Xtick');
new_ticks = (12 * log2((f / 440) + 69))
set(gca,'Xticklabels', new_ticks)
```

This keeps the x-axis scaling the same, but changes the tick labels according to the formula you gave.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for that. Edited my question so it'll be clear.